# Double Expectation in Moment Generating Function

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation, moment-generating-function

**Context**

Assume a game using a fair 6 sided dice ends when one rolls a 6. A random variable N is the total number of throws. N is distributed such that:

$p_N(n) = \frac{5}{6}^{n-1}\frac{1}{6}$

Assume you win 1 point for an even number, and -1 point for an odd number.

$X_i$ is a random variable denoting point's gained from the $i^{th}$ throw s.t. $X_i = 1$ or $X_i = -1$

Random variable $W$ is the total number of points obtained at the end of the game.

$W = \sum_{i=1}^NX_i$

**Question:**

Why is the moment generating function described as

$M_w(t) = E(e^{tW}) = E(E(e^{tW}|N)) = E(M_{W|N}(t)$)

Specifically I'm interested in the intuition behind the double expectation. Thanks!

Comment: Have you attempted to compute $E(e^{tW})$ directly without conditioning on $N$?

Comment: Yes i didn't really know how to think about this, because we don't know what N actually is. Only how it's distributed, i just struggled to connect the steps shown in my head. For example does it imply that:

$e^{tW} = E(e^{tW}|N)$? Thanks!

Comment: You have written that "$N$ is the total number of throws."  That's what it actually is. Are you familiar with the laws of conditional expectation, especially the "tower law" *aka* [Law of Total Expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)?

Comment: Also an Expectation of something gives us a constant right? So surely $E(E(a)) = E(a)$? The fact that clearly isn't the case here, otherwise why write it, implies that i don't quite understand what's going on with the double expectations and need help...

Comment: No i wasn't familiar with that, but that is already quite helpful, thank you!

Comment: I found a few examples of this approach worked out here on CV: check out the links from [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=conditional%20expectation%20moment%20generating&searchOn=3).